# Exclude returned orders & Home Office orders from the orders dataset

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]
[image]I am trying to Exclude returned orders & Home Office orders from the orders dataset

I have 2 datasets `order`  and `returns`
in order dataset it's order summary in `returns dataset` there is column `return yes or no` `order_id` , `region`

```
select * from orders where order_id not in 
(select a.order_id, b.returned 
from orders a
join returns b
on a.order_id = b.order_id
where a.category = 'home_office') ;
```

while doing this i am getting this error `Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)` 
i just want to figure out  `how to exclude return= yes orders using join`

i want `order table as it is` however if based on table 2 `return if order has been returned it should be excluded from table 1 when i see results`

Comment: does the solution below works ?

Comment: please share data set indicating what do you have and what do you want to see

Comment: please have a look

Comment: you can simply join and in the join condition put AND condition. You want to exclude the data where returned is true, so you should say : join returns b
on a.order_id = b.order_id and b.returns = 'no' [if this does't work then do: AND b.returns = FALSE

Comment: in the returned there is only `yes` not no

Comment: you said it has yes or no

Comment: it has only 'yes'